# Flutter - How can I make these Containers to work like a Button?

Tags: flutter

This is my first App and my first steps in programming. I started with designing the Homepage. Now I want the Containers to act like Buttons, so that I can navigate to other pages. I just can't figure out a way to do so. Maybe u guys got some ideas.
Do i have to delete the 5 Containers and add 5 buttons and redesign them?
I Think there might be a problem since I wrote the buttons as widget?

The Code so far:

```
//import 'dart:html';


  import 'package:apptierpark/Anfahrt.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  void main () => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Tierpark()));

  class Tierpark extends StatelessWidget {
    get assets => null;

    get image => null;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60.0),
            child: AppBar(
          title: Text('Tierpark Marzahne',
          style: TextStyle (
            color: Colors.black,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 45,
            fontFamily: 'Amatic',
            shadows: [
              Shadow(
                blurRadius: 10.0,
                color: Colors.white,
                offset: Offset(5.0, 5.0),
              )
            ]
          )),
          flexibleSpace: Image(
            image: AssetImage('images/urwald4.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        ),

        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage('images/bamboo.jpg'), fit: BoxFit.fill)),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: 
          <Widget>[ 
            MenuButton2('Bewohner',),
            SizedBox(height: 50),
            MenuButton2('Parkplan'),
            SizedBox(height: 40),
            MenuButton2('Zeiten & Preise'),
            SizedBox(height: 40),
            MenuButton2('Anfahrt'),
            SizedBox(height: 40),
            MenuButton2 ('Über Uns')
            ] 
            ,)
        ,)
        )
        );
    }
  }





  //Button Mainpage Neu

  class MenuButton2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  const MenuButton2(this.title);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: const Color(0xFFa9d470),
      border: Border.all(
        color: const Color(0xFFa9d470)
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.9),
          spreadRadius: 10,
          blurRadius: 12

        )
      ]
    ),
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.38,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.11,
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text (title,
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 50,
      fontFamily: 'Amatic',
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
    ),))
  );
  }
  }
```

Comment: You can wrap containers with GestureDetector, or InkWell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `Container` with `GestureDetector` or `InkWell` like this and call functions with it's properties,

```
  class MenuButton2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final int buttonId;
  const MenuButton2(this.title,this.buttonId);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {
    if(buttonId == 1){
    // do 1
    }
    else if(buttonId == 2){
    // do 2
    }
    else if(buttonId == 3){
    // do 3
    }
    else if(buttonId == 4){
    // do 4
    }
    else {
    // do 5
    }
    },
    child:Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: const Color(0xFFa9d470),
        border: Border.all(
          color: const Color(0xFFa9d470)
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.9),
            spreadRadius: 10,
            blurRadius: 12
          )
        ]
      ),
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.38,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.11,
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text (title,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 50,
        fontFamily: 'Amatic',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
      ),
    ),
   ),
 );
}
```

And in the place where you call the function do this,

```
...
<Widget>[ 
  MenuButton2('Bewohner', 1),
  SizedBox(height: 50),
  MenuButton2('Parkplan', 2),
  SizedBox(height: 40),
  MenuButton2('Zeiten & Preise', 3),
  SizedBox(height: 40),
  MenuButton2('Anfahrt', 4),
  SizedBox(height: 40),
  MenuButton2 ('Über Uns', 5)
],
...
```

Comment: i wrapped the container in Inkwell and added onTab to a new route. Alll the "Buttons" lead to the same route. Is there a way to lead all of them to a single route without writing it piece per piece?

Comment: Do you want to call different function for each button?

Comment: yes. I thought it might could work just like I did with the text. Each button has a different text.

Comment: Yes, just like you sent the `title` you can send a unique id for each button. Check the updated answer :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Accept my answer if it's solved, @Schamaleon :)

Answer (score 0):

Add your `Container` inside `Inkwell` or `GestureDetector` Widgtes refer below code hope its help to you.

[Inkwell Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html)

[GestureDetector Widgets](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

```
 // GestureDetector( you use GestureDetector also here instead of InkWell Widgets
  InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        print('button Pressed');
        // Call your onPressed or onTap function here
      },
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(30),
          ),
        ),
        height: 50,
        width: 200,
        child: Text(
          'Search',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

Your result screen -> [image]